# How does pip-compile manage its input and output files?

Tags: python, pip

When invoking `pip-compile` like this:

```
pip-compile -i https://pypi.our-company.com/ 
      --no-emit-trusted-host --no-emit-find-links
       requirements/requirements.in.txt 
       2> requirements/hac-reqs1.txt
```

the following surprising [to me anyways..] behavior occurs:

- there is no output to stdout (it goes to stderr which is why i use `2>`)
- The input file `requirements/requirements.in.txt` is overwritten with the  output contents (which are also the same as the stderr output)

I just want a more normal behavior along the lines of either

- `pip-compile <input_file> <output_file>`
- `pip-compile <input_file> >  <output_file>`

Is that possible?  If not then how is the `<input file>` supposed to be protected from being overwritten ?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pip-tools/#output-file

Comment: @phd  Thanks - the `pip-compile --help` did not provide that level of info . Feel free to make an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented in the [`README.rst`](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools/blob/master/README.rst#output-file) (and published at [GitHub](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools#output-file) and [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pip-tools/#output-file)):

> To output the pinned requirements in a filename other than `requirements.txt`, use `--output-file filename`

Comment: thx I was not familiar with the pip-tools repo but that will change